# Figuring out dependencies for SOAP::Lite

Tags: xml, perl, ubuntu, soap, module

I maintain some scripts that read XML data from our data provider's SOAP methods.  Earlier this morning I discovered my scripts on my production server weren't downloading data, although the ones on my test server had no issues at all.  The errors were being generated at XML::Parser on line 187.  I suspect the code making the call to XML::Parser was mangling $arg somehow, so I made an attempt to find out what that code was and see how XML::Parser relates to SOAP::Lite.  I could see no obvious relationship.

I know that my test and prod systems do have different versions of the modules in use, but I want to know exactly what's being affected before I propose that prod be updated through CPAN (I'm not prod's system owner; we've been updating modules via apt).  I'd greatly appreciate any ideas.

Comment: ok, so it is on line 187; sounds interesting..

Answer (score 0):

Try out something like [Module::PrintUsed](https://metacpan.org/module/Module%3a%3aPrintUsed) to get a list of used dependencies with its version numbers.